# How to align code on an equals sign in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Using **visual studio** I would like to **align** following code snippet by **equal sign**. 
How do I do that?

```
var contact2 = new Contact();
contact2.Email = "john.doe@gmail.com";
contact2.FirstName = "john";
contact2.LastName = "doe"; 

var contact2        = new Contact();
contact2.Email      = "john.doe@gmail.com";
contact2.FirstName  = "john";
contact2.LastName   = "doe";
```

Comment: [Aligning code in columns with ReSharper and Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/11/28/aligning-code-columns-resharper-rider/)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce the following result:
[image]

Therefore I had to configure the following settings under *ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Tabs, Indents, Alignment*:
[image]

However, I wasn't able to align the `new` statement.